# Make fish functions private

Tags: fish

I defined several helper functions that I only use in one specific fish script. I put them inside the wrapper function but you can still find them via autocompletion.

How can I hide them from auto completion and limit their scope to `private`?

```
function outer
   function inner_func
       echo "I still find this function via automplete"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Fish **does not** have private functions, but [it is possible this feature will be available in future versions](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1799#issuecomment-69683844). In the meantime, try using the following technique, a naming convention, or both.

#### `functions -e function_name`

Very close to what you need. You can use `functions -e function_name` before the end of the block to erase it from the global scope.

```
function outer
    function inner_func
        echo "I still find this function via automplete."
        echo "Not anymore!!"
        functions -e inner_func
    end
    # Let's test this!
    inner_func
end


$ outer
I still find this function via automplete.
Not anymore!!
$ inner_func
fish: Unknown command 'inner_func'
```

#### Naming Convention

- `_my_module_func_name`

This does not erase the function from the global scope, but it is a general good practice to avoid overriding existing functions unintentionally.

#### Notes

Functions declared inside a main function file (or functions inside other functions like `inner_func`) will be available *only* after its parent function is invoked at least once (this is fish lazy function autoloading), and exist only for the duration of that particular shell session.

Comment: I'd put `functions -e _funcname` as first statement in the function definition: it simplifies the case where you have multiple return statements within the function body.